# Express reverse diode voltage drop as a function of temperature

Tags: diodes, resistance, temperature, voltage-measurement

I've made a simple temperature meter, with means of series of Ge diodes, followed by 10k resistor.
I am applying +5V to topmost diode cathode, and measuring voltage drop between resistor and ground

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFDQ6t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now I am trying to find formula for V(T). It's totally non linear, Probably I could make conversion in software. But, I need to know, what does it looks like?

PS. If interested, for a calibration I know that Rdiode is ~20k for +5C and ~1k for 20C. And I only need narrow range -20C to +30C for rude street temperature measurement.

Comment: Where the hell do you still take Ge diodes from? These been obsolete since the mid-60s, roughly?

Comment: Which also means your Ge diode is decades old stock, and probably not built to modern precision – so, really, the worst positive temperature coefficient thermosensor you could pick. What's the motivation to use exactly this diode?=

Comment: (by the way, the relationship is exponential – Shockley diode equation, the most very basic equation to describe diodes)

Comment: @MarcusMüller From father of my friend, he was old soviet electrician, and had a lot of interesting stuff. I've used it just because it is by hand, precision does not matter alot to me. I know nowadays there are precise sensor ICs, I dont want to buy specialized sensors. Shockley diode equation is tied to current, I dont have ammeter by hand. How to expose voltage, (but not current), for this simple circuit?

Comment: hmmmm you're already measuring the current. You know that the voltage U you're measuring is R·I :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's too hard for my simple head. I want to get rid of currents, to tie to voltage divider: `Vd/Vr = Rd/Rr` with knowing that `Vd+Vr=5volt`. That is at least understandable. So could I think that diode is a non-linear thermo-resistor, which has resistance as a temp function `R(T)`? So I come to initial question - Expose V(T) (or R(T) ). But everything that is exposed on the internet - is useless `I(T)` which just cant be plugged here.

Comment: `Rd(T) = Rr * (5-Vr)/Vr` Here `Rr` is known constant, `Vr` is measured, all I lack is `Rd(T)`: *Diode resistance as a function of temp*. Could you please show me correct formula without a current? So at final I can expose T = func(Vr) and make my conversions in software

Comment: You are measuring the reverse leakage current - not the reverse voltage. The reverse leakage current is exponential with respect to temperature. You would do better measuring the forward voltage drop of a silicon transistor, or even better a diode connected transistor.

Comment: Calc done. `T ~= 3*ln(-Vr/(Vr-1))+14`, where `Vr` is normalized to `(0..1)` range. So, with given ADC, my simple is able to measure from -5C to 25C.

Comment: @KevinWhite I may give it a try tomorrow.. Can I ask you - Why would it be better, ant how? Could it allow me to extend range to -20C .. +30C ? Btw, 0.7V is far away from 5V, should I connect 5-6 of them in series?

Comment: @xakepp35 - the forward drop is more predictable, linear (not exponential as for the leakage current). Uses modern available devices. A better approach still is to measure the voltage at two currents and from there compute the absolute temperature - that technique is used in most temperature sensor ICs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Germanium diodes are not obsolete, they are better than silicon ones and have better temperature stability and parameters. The function that you are looking for is a datasheet parameter. You can easily measure it, its a function of current or voltage change based on temperature. Its called a diode temperature characteristic.

The characteristic will change in quadrants 1 and 3 based on the temperature, meaning the voltage and current through the diode will change with the temperature in a border.

[image]

The [characteristic](https://www.ques10.com/p/4574/explain-the-effect-of-temperature-on-pn-junction-1/) and the original image.

[Formulas](http://www.kennethkuhn.com/students/ee351/diode_characteristics.pdf) and explanations.

Comment: I would say that they ARE obsolete.  They're no longer manufactured, (except MAYBE by some small outfits that I'm unaware of), no longer used in mainstream manufacturing, and though they had a smaller forward drop than silicon PN junction diodes they are pretty leaky.  Most or all of what's for sale is NOS.

Comment: @JohnD It's of no importance - are they manufactured/obsolete or not - totally out of current scope. Consider they DO exists and alredy working in my circuit. Only 2 questions that matters are: "Forward vs reverse" and "Is a experimentally found formula is correct?" Reverse seems to be more sensitive, and formula works for day-to-night temps, dont know how good/precise would it be for +30C ..

Comment: I didnt mean to offend you, Germanium diodes are used in military technology do to their much better properties tha silicium ones. In the user market its not impossible that you have not heard of them much and that you don't use them. Silicium is only used because its cheaper, not because its better.

Comment: As per answer. 1. Old Ge diodes are NOT better than silicone - leaky and parameters vary alot. But they may be useful for measuring temperature. 2. Diode temperature characteristic is NOT function of time. 3. Link is broken. 4. Answer is not answering question. Missing formula, allowing to find temperature based on measured voltage drop, (or resistance/voltage drop, based on temperature, that may be converted to required)

Comment: @JohnD John, by the way, [they are sold in big russian store only for 0.1-0.2$ per part](https://www.chipdip.ru/catalog/popular/germanievyj-diod) so after quarantine you may come to civilisation, and buy some if your country does not manufacture/retail them ;-)

Comment: I will address all concerns as soon as I can.

Comment: I have fixed all problems, but I don't agree with you that silicone diodes are better. I note your oppinion and stick by my decision. Here you can find a little more.
http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Germanium-diode-circuit.php

Comment: Yeah, they are cool. I didnt said that silicone diodes are better. That was another man, read nicknames pafter comments/posts. I am just question author, and stated that germanium is not better or worse, it is another. I cant make my temp sensor it with Si diodes, like I do with Ge diodes. Si diodes will likely require amplifying transistor.. I've accepted your answer. And i've came to my own solution, which i posted bottom. Feel free to read and comment it, if you're interested :)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the task in a following manner.

1. Choose a proper resistor.

   - Given temperature range, that I to want measure most precisely, -10C to +30C, midpoint is +10C.
   - My reference voltage is 4.95V, wned reverse-applied to my system of diodes and a 47K resistor in series, it gives almost 50/50 voltage drop across resistor and diodes series, at my desired +10C (Actually diodes are 44K at that temp, but that is not a big deal, following would correct us)
2. Calibrate system. Sample input with arduino and ref voltage. Take 2 temperature points at both sides and notice, that:

   - At +12.6C voltage drop across 47K resistor is 0.616*4.95V
   - At +3.9C voltage drop is 0.315*4.95V
3. Assume that nonlinearity is provided by compression function of form `y = 1/(1+exp(-x))`[image]
4. Solve this stuff, [with any tool of taste](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20y%20%3D%201%2F%281%2Bexp%28-x%29%29). No need doing math, but better to have a clue how to properly rotate/adjust it for your task. You'll get function to get rid of nonlinearity: [image]
5. To adjust and scale I need func like `y = k*x+b` where `x` is linearized(normalized(measured voltage)).

   - `ln(0.616/(1-0.616))` = 0.4726
   - `ln(0.616/(1-0.616))` = -0.7768
6. Solve system of linear equation, [with any tool of taste](https://matrixcalc.org/en/slu.html#solve-using-inverse-matrix-method%28%7B%7B2363/5000,1,0,0,63/5%7D,%7B-%28971/1250%29,1,0,0,39/10%7D%7D%29), in order to get `k` and `b`:

   - k ~= x7
   - b ~= +9.3C
7. Enjoy the resulting formula:

   - `temperatureCelsius = 7*ln(Vadc/(4.95-Vadc))+9.3C`
8. Also we know that midpoint is at +9.3C.
9. Also looking at graphed formula:
   [image]
   we may know that arduino 10-bit adc is theoretically capable of measuring:

   - from -30C to +50C with ~1C precision
   - from -20C to +40C with ~0.1C precision
   - from -10C to +30C with ~0.01C precision
     Which, for our typical outdoor temperatures range is nice, and well enough for my task.

PS. I think this info may be useful, if someone else would want to make something like this cheap diy temp sensor, not going to shop, but from old parts from their attic. Best regards!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it would help others. If you decide to buy parts from the shop, you can try LM335. Its a good temperature sensor and when you connect 2 of them, your accuracy increases.

Comment: @CFCBazarcom Maybe, but it's range is too huge, and unamplified sensitivity is small. Along with it, probably a preamp could be used as some frontend, like in this useful [articles](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/february2016_AnalogFrontEnds)

Comment: It works great, its calibrated for Kelvin, you can check the basic circuit without calibration in the datasheet. It has 1degree accuracy, its a professional device and gives 10mv/degree. A problem can come from the resistor, which is affected by the temperature, you should pick a 1% resistor or lower. With a 10bit ADC you do not need an amplifier. Most arduinos have a 10bit ADC, despite that I don't recommend arduino.
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snis160e/snis160e.pdf?ts=1587916734125